# How can i check how much specific g++ version support C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I know [this website](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) describing how much specific g++ version support `C++11`

But It seem not clear for me, Because if we consider `<thread>` or `<chrono>`, i don't know which `Language Feature` represent these functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with these two things you mentioned is that these are not features of the compiler, but of the library. Another problem is that support for them depends on the "implementation", so for example it may work on Linux, but not work for given "variant" of MinGW on Windows...

Here is the website that answers your question - documentation of libstdc++ (used in GCC): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011